# Error in uploading file to server using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to upload one excel sheet to server . It works perfectly fine but sometimes it breaks. Getting error as no such file or directory.

```
// Request = request.payload.file, id= unique string

const brinksFilePath = './uploads/';
const fs = require('fs');

let uploadFile = async (request, id) => {
    
    let data = request;
    let type = id + '/';
    let name = data.hapi.filename;
    let path = brinksFilePath + type + name;

    try {

       
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

        if (!fs.existsSync(brinksFilePath + type)) {
            console.log("Path not found making directory ")
            fs.mkdirSync(brinksFilePath + type);
        }
        
        file.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));

        data.pipe(file);
        

        data.on('end', (err) => {
           
            const ret = {
                filename: data.hapi.filename,
                headers: data.hapi.headers
            }
        })
         

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error -----", error)
    }

return  path
    
}
```

Error is as below

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Desktop\api\uploads\aegrghthtrhtre\REPORT_02.2021.xlsx']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   'C:\Users\Desktop\api\uploads\aegrghthtrhtre\REPORT_02.2021.xlsx' }
```

If I browse the same path in my system there is a folder created but I don't see any file.

Comment: Try opening stream after making sure the folder exists? So, move this line down `const file = fs.createWriteStream(path); ` and try.

Comment: That works. Thank you @Rehmat